# Update the ConcurrentHashMap in a thread safe way

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I am in the process of benchmarking few methods in my client code to see how much time those methods are taking. So I have written a Multithreading program which will spawn Multiple threads and then I will be measuring how much time those methods are taking in the Client code and Server side code as well.

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` declared as

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>();
```

Now I am trying to find out, how much calls came back in X milliseconds, so I am storing those numbers in the above map. So the above map will store something like this-

```
KEY will be Milliseconds
and VALUE will be Number of calls came back in those milliseconds.
```

Below is the code, I have got.

```
final long start = System.nanoTime();

method.getInformation();

final long end = System.nanoTime() - start;
final long key = end / 1000000L;
boolean done = false;
while(!done) {
    Long oldValue = map.putIfAbsent(key, 1L);
    if(oldValue != null) {
        done = map.replace(key, oldValue, oldValue + 1);
    } else {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

I am trying to see whether is there any problem with the above code?

Why I am asking is if I am running my `Multithreading program`, then the `server CPU usage` usually goes to around `80-90%`. But If I remove the above benchmarking code from the server side code, then the `CPU usage` don't go to `80-90%`. So that is the reason, I am trying to see whether is there any better way to write the above benchmarking code which can fulfill the same above scenario?

Thanks for the help.

**Updated:-**

I was monitoring the CPU and MEMORY usage on the server side using the TOP command in unix-

```
top - 17:13:18 up 25 days, 23:24,  4 users,  load average: 1.72, 1.43, 1.04
Tasks: 114 total,   1 running, 111 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
Cpu0  : 79.2%us,  5.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 23.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.9%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 83.7%us,  3.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 40.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.9%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   6127684k total,  5122736k used,  1004948k free,   240436k buffers
Swap:  1331196k total,        0k used,  1331196k free,  2485984k cached
```

Below is the snapshot while it was running, I just captured

Comment: Any idea how much memory you are using for this map?  Are there really supposed to be 1 million entries in it?  Are you watching your GC load?  Make sure using Jconsole that the free memory isn't going critical.

Comment: If your multiple threads all write to one shared object, they will end up queuing to get access to that object. My guess is that will make performance look worse per thread than is realistic. Might it be better to have each thread store its own data, then merge the data for analysis only once the multithreaded task has finished?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't work that way @Arkanon.  You queue to get access to a range of buckets -- not an object.  I would expect that the blocked/run ration would be okay for decent sized maps.  Having each thread keep thread-local stats is going to multiply the memory requirements for sure.

Comment: @Arkanon, yeah that sounds like a good option. Can you provide an example how to achieve that? By that, I will be able to understand and can implement it in my code as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Gray, I am not sure how much memory my map is going to use. Any thoughts how can i check that? My server is running on ubuntu box. I am also not watching GC load as well. Not sure as well how to launch JConsole my ubuntu machine.

Comment: You need to learn how to run Jconsole.  It should be in `/usr/bin/` or something.  You need to be running your program using JMX args.  See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/javavm.html

Comment: I guess, it is not in my control - See this- `uname@phx539:~$ jconsole
The program 'jconsole' is currently not installed.  To run 'jconsole' please ask                                                                                                                                                               your administrator to install the package 'openjdk-6-jdk'`

Comment: Ah, good point @Gray. I see now that ConcurrentHashMap has a [constructor which takes a concurrencLevel parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap%28int,%20float,%20int%29) to allow you to say how many threads will access it at once, so that contention is reduced as much as possible.

Comment: Didn't actually know of that parameter and I've been using CHM for years now.  I'd try increasing your `-Xmx` memory setting before fooling with that.

Comment: @Gray, I updated my question with some information, it might help you in giving some more suggestion. That information I got from the server side.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some performance information @FarhanJamal.  I was able to do 1 million in 12.9 seconds.

Comment: @Gray ... note that was on a Mac.  The OS could be significant.

Comment: Certainly @StephenC.  It was just to give the poster some relative performance numbers.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a quick test with your time checking code and was able to run 1 *million* of them in 8.8 seconds on my quad core 2013 Macbook Pro.  This means each call cost less than 8ns (since my timing is wall clock and takes into account the thread stuff).  This is pretty cheap IMO.  I was sticking random values from 0 to 1000000 with 100 threads and ended up with a heap size of 631k entries which seemed to take less than 20-30mb of core.

Seems to me that your call time code is not a big performance problem.  I wonder if each of the threads are touching a lot of memory and the only thing your code is doing is hitting a memory barrier.  Might be interesting to replace the code with a single update of a `volatile` field or something to force a barrier to see if you get the same behavior.

---

I don't immediately see any problems with your code and I wouldn't think that it would be a large performance problem.

I do wonder how big that map is getting however.  Seems to be that if you are running it for a long time with a large number of entries in the map, the memory requirements is going to be significant.  You might try increasing the memory with a `-Xmx` argument.

If it is memory then the CPU issues may be GC related.  I'd use Jconsole to see if you are running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are some potential performance issues here.

1. Your benchmarking code is adding two calls to `System.nanoTime()` to each request.  Depending on how much *real* work is involved in the requests, those calls could be significant.
2. While you have attempted to reduce the concurrency bottleneck by using `ConcurrentHashMap`, that doesn't eliminate it entirely.  Indeed, if you have lots of requests that take the same number of milliseconds, there will be a bottleneck on that particular counter.  If there is contention on a particular counter, that will result in "spinning" as different threads compete to update it.
3. If (hypothetically) the map got really big, you could start getting memory usage related issues; e.g. a larger working set, increased cache and TLB contention, thrashing.

But the bottom line is that any performance measurement code you add is likely to alter the performance characteristics of the system.

Comment: FYI: I just did a performance run @Stephen and did 1 million of them in 12.8 seconds on my Mac laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Performance/Resource Usage issues:

- Reading and writing to a HashMap during each invocation can be expensive, a concurrent hashmap more so.  It's not required.
- Also you call System.nanoTime(), which can be expensive, and you do this on every iteration. It's not required.

My suggestion

- declare a static running counter on number of times method is executed
- in a synchronised block, increment the counter
- when counter reaches threshhold (e.g. 1000), *then* determine elapsed time in millisec
- record elapsed time in a list

  ```
  static List<long> methodElapsedMillisList = new ArrayList<long>();
  final int methodCountBlock = 1000; 
  static long methodCountStartMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
  static int methodCount = 0;
  static Object methodCountMonitorObj = new Object();


  // within instrumented method:
  synchronised (methodCountMonitorObj) {
         methodCount++;
         if (methodCount > methodCountBlock ) {
              long newMethodCountStartMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
              long elapsedMillis = newMethodCountStartMillis - methodCountStartMillis;
              methodCountStartMillis = newMethodCounterStartMillis;
              methodElapsedMillisList.add(elapsedMillis);
              methodCount = 0;
         }
  }
  ```